# How to access OrderBy clause from MethodCallExpression

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees

I have a custom LINQ provider that processes a [MethodCallExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) that has a [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549264(v=vs.110).aspx) clause inside it. How can I get hold of the [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549264(v=vs.110).aspx) clause so that I may process it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, here is how.

```
    public class QueryContext<T>
    {
        void Execute(MethodCallExpression dsQueryExpression)
        {
            var orderByFinder = new OrderByFinder();
            var orderByExpression = orderByFinder.GetOrderBy(dsQueryExpression);
            // .. Continue on processing the OrderBy expression
        }
    }

    internal class OrderByFinder : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        MethodCallExpression _orderByExpression;

        public MethodCallExpression GetOrderBy(Expression expression)
        {
            Visit(expression);
            return _orderByExpression;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
        {
            if (expression.Method.Name == "OrderBy") _orderByExpression = expression;

            Visit(expression.Arguments[0]);

            return expression;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @MBoros Yes, my finds the bottom OrderBy clause which suits my use case as the OData data source I'm accessing only supports order by on the first level of the query.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Other than `OrderBy`, there are `OrderByDescending` plus the `ThenBy`/`ThenByDescending`

Comment: @xanatos Yes, I have implemented those too. Thank you though.